# NULL defined as 0 by my compiler std lib: is it correct?

Tags: c, null

The standard library of my C compiler defines `NULL` this way:

```
#define NULL 0
```

I would expect:

```
#define NULL ((void *)0)
```

Could someone tell me which one is correct and why?

Thank you!

Comment: why would a void* change it significantly?

Comment: For me `0` is an `int` so it is not a `void*`. Am I wrong?

Comment: Everything is a number. My MSVC library defines it both ways, depending on C or C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last revisions of C standard, C99 and C11, equates the null quantity to zero or null pointer.
From **ISO/IEC 9899:201x §6.3.2.3 Pointers**, point 3:

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression
>   cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant. If a null
>   pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting
>   pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a
>   pointer to any object or function.

So what you see is a perfectly compliant NULL declaration of a C99-C11 compiler as opposed to the previous `#define NULL ((void *)0)` of pre C99 compilers.

Comment: So is it correct to say that `#define NULL ((void *)0)` is *pre C99* (excluded) and `#define NULL 0` is *post C99* (included)?

Comment: @Plouff Yes absolutely. You have to consider that using the macro `NULL` it will equate to the correct definition liked by the compiler you are using. This guarantee the compatibility of compilation between preC99 and postC99 compilers.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. And that's absolutely great: I am working on a project that redefines NULL the wrong way... **So can we say that redefining NULL is a bad practice?**

Comment: Even K&R C a zero value in any pointer context to be converted to the proper NULL pointer of that type by the compiler. So, `#defined NULL 0` has been correct since day one.

Comment: @rpy: So where did `#define NULL ((void *)0)` came from?

Comment: In K&R C everything was an `int`. A declaration as `foo(a)` that would trigger at least a bunch of warnings in a modern compiler was legal and meant: `int foo(int a)`. The integer and the pointer **must have same size** so they were interchangeable. Starting from first ISO C, known as C88, some modification to the language were actuated in the aim to make it more portable (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#ANSI_C_and_ISO_C). One of the point was the stronger typing of data from where the distinction between int and pointer. Then the prototypes and so on...

Comment: @Plouff Redefining NULL maybe an unconventional practice I would say. In C you can do what you want if you know what you are doing. If there is a good reason for redefining NULL it could be acceptable, it depends. I made a redefinition of the stdlib `malloc` function on a  compiler having defective `msize()` to make it work for a known open source cross compiler product. If you can have a look to the first versions of MS MFC you could get shocked by the level of hacking they have done...

Comment: @Plouff Reason for using void pointer cast is to give compiler warning or error if try to assign NULL to an int.

Comment: @Frankie_C: Many thanks for the history of C evolutions and for the feedback based on your experience :)!

Comment: @user694733: Ok! Even if I don't get why would someone try that!

Comment: There were no changes in this area in C99. In all versions of ISO C the compiler can define `NULL` as either `0` or `((void *)0)`, amongst other options

Answer (score 4):

In C language, the two way you said are both correct, both of they can be convert to other pointer that point to whatever object(any type) automatically, but in C++ language, **`#define NULL ((void *)0)`** is wrong, because void* can't be convert to other pointer automatically just like C.

Comment: Upvoted. You're right, this is one of the cases, and are many, where **C++ is sayd more strong typed than C**. But I still like much more C...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the differences btw C and C++.